# Action Script 3. How to disable Allow Click function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, actionscript, flash-cs5

I'm creating Flash "memory" game, Idea to discover 2 equal cards, but I have 1 problem.
When I discover second card program write: "Wrong turn" and It is shown for 1 second, but at this time I can discover other cards, 3rd, 4th etc. I need to add something like "AllowClick = false" function, till 2 cards are shown.

As I understand I need to use this:
`...RemoveEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);` Could you help me to use It correct?

[DEMO](http://padekime.eu/ab.html)

Here is part of my code:

```
            else
            {
                trace("Wrong");
                _message = "Wrong";
                message_txt.text = _message;
                 _secondCard = event.currentTarget;


                var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1); //antros kortos atsivertimo laikas
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, flipBack);
                timer.start();


            }
        }
        protected function flipBack(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    _firstCard.gotoAndPlay("flipBack");
    _firstCard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
    _firstCard = _secondCard = undefined;             
}
```

I hope you understood my question. Could you help me, please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to set `.mouseEnabled` to `false` and `.mouseChildren` to `false` to all other elements? See here: [as3 mouseEnabled still a problem for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248381/as3-mouseenabled-still-a-problem-for-me)

Comment: Thank you for answer. i have tried .mouseEnabled = false for _card, _firstCard, _secondCard, but the same, not helps for me.

Comment: No , you need to set these parameters to all cards **except** the first and second